# Strategy to map product and stores, maybe country too?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

The way i see it:
There are say 10 million stores in a country, (much more in reality).
There are atleast 50 million unique products being sold across these 10 million stores. (again much more in reality).

So to map this out I guess it will something like: pk_id, store_id, product_id

But this way we will have 500 million rows per country x even take 100 countries = 50 billion rows. Not a very efficient table to be doing lookups, read/writes etc from.

Is there a better way to map product, stores and then add countries also in the mix?

I have not added in online stores or online products which will almost triple this size.

Answer (score 0):

Each store is in a specific country.

You can use one table to store the realtionship between stores and countries, and another table to hold the relationship between stores and items sold in that store.

To make lookups efficient you need to add indexes.

Comment: If I want to see the unique or common products being sold by the Apple brand across say even 50 countries would it map out well? There will be a brand table higher than the store table to hold brand to store relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store everything in one table. Here's how you should do it:

1. Store products in a `products` table (product_id, etc / Index product_id)
2. Store store locations and countries in a separate table (id, store_id, country_id / make one index called store_country containing the columns store_id, country_id)

This way you can have 50 million products (50 million rows) and 50 million stores in 38 (random) countries, 1,900,000,000 rows assuming every store has a location in each country and each store sells every product (unrealistic).

I like big numbers.

Answer (score 0):

- One table for Products
- One table for Countries (use ISO country code as PK)
- One table for Stores (include a foreign key to the Countries table)
- One table for mapping Products and Stores. Use `{product_id, store_id}` as primary key)

If your company is anything like most of the companies out there, I think you will find that not all products are being sold in all stores, making the mapping table much smaller than you anticipate. (If all stores sell all products always you don't need the mapping table)